# jasmine not loading js files from the 'src' directory

Tags: javascript, maven, jasmine

I've managed to successfully build my maven project which uses the [jasmine-maven-plugin](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin) to put the source and test javascript files in the right places.  When I have a simple test such as:

```
describe('true', function() {
    it('should be true', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    })
})
```

the whole thing builds with no problems, and all the jasmine specs pass.  But when I try to create an instance of an object that I've outlined in one of the files that are included target/jasmine/src folder, I get a "ReferenceError: "Stat" is not defined" error.

```
describe('stat test',function() {
    var stat = new Stat();

    it('get data',function() {
        stat.data = 13;
        expect(stat.getData()).toBe(13);
    });
});
```

Are the js files not loading properly?  Totally stumped here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set up in the correct way jasmine? It seems that jasmine can't find your js files, here you have an example of the maven configuration:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal> test </goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
             <jsSrcDir> main/www/js </jsSrcDir>    <---HERE you define the source directory
             <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
             <sourceIncludes>       <---- HERE you specifies which files you include into the test
                <include>libs/jquery-1.7.1.js</include>
                <include>libs/underscore.js</include>
                <include>**/*.js</include>
             </sourceIncludes>
             <sourceExcludes> <----- HERE you define the files that you exclude
                  <exclude>jsonresponses-mock.js</exclude>
                  <exclude>libs/jquery.mockjax.js</exclude>
             </sourceExcludes>
             <jsTestSrcDir> test/www/fakeJs </jsTestSrcDir> <---Define your Test source Dir
                   <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                   <browserVersion>FIREFOX_3</browserVersion>
                   <serverPort>8234</serverPort>
                   <specDirectoryName>specs</specDirectoryName>
         </configuration>
</plugin>
```

At the bottom of this page: http://searls.github.com/jasmine-maven-plugin you have all the possibles tags.
Check if you have your pom in the correct way... Hope it can help!!

Comment: yes, my pom.xml looks just like this, except I leave out the jsTestSrcDir tag as it defaults to src/test/javascript where my tests are.  When I run 'maven install' I get all the correct js files in the folder 'target/jasmine/src', where they should be.  still, they are not being loaded from here for some reason.

Comment: Did you try using require? an example is: var Blog = require('../MyClass').MyClass; at the top in your describe. In this link you have an example: http://gregs.tcias.co.uk/2011/07/12/first-steps-with-jasmine/

Comment: yes, I tried this as well. I get 'ReferenceError: "require" is not defined'.  Any other ideas? Thanks for your help, this has been driving me crazy for days!

Comment: mm the order of the files beetwen the sourceIncludes is important put first your libraries and after it put the path (from jsSrcDir) to your Stat object.

Comment: still no dice.  Is there a working example online somewhere that I can follow?

Comment: so I got it working but only when I include every single js file in its own <preloadSource> tag.  Is this a bug?

Comment: According to official documentation (http://searls.github.com/jasmine-maven-plugin/) preloadSource tag is used for scripts that need to be loaded before other scripts. In your case you need that your class is loaded before the specifications. When I worked with jasmine last year with the label sourceIncludes was sufficient to specify that order. The pom above I took from a working project (I only change the paths).

Comment: Ah!  Figured it out.  the source includes have their root directory in the <sourcedir> defined just before.  Seems obvious now that I've got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

After much mental strain and not much luck, I just modified the plugin to ignore perceived javascript errors so that everything would compile.  Lo and behold, it all worked!  Scripts were just being added out of order.  For those interested, I added "client.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false)" at line #90 in TestMojo.java, so now when the  tag is set to false (default), javascript errors are ignored.